# Returning a set from function

Tags: coq

I'd like to change the function `boolfunction` by adding an extra case for the `true,true` match case. Now the function returns `true` for the case `true,true` and I want to code that this case can be `false` as well. I wonder if there is a way to code this in Coq.

```
 Definition boolfunction  (c d : bool) : bool := 
  match c,d with
   | _, false=> true
   |false, true => false 
   | true,true => true
   end.
```

Answer (score 0):

A function can produce a different type instead of `bool`. If you want to produce more than one value, one way is to produce a list of values. That is one way of representing a nondeterministic function.

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition boolfunction (c d : bool) : list bool :=
  match c, d with
  | _, false => [true]
  | false, true => [false]
  | true, true => [true, false]
  end.
```

Without more details about what you are looking for it's hard to be more accurate.